# How to set word limit in a text box with Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I need to set a limit on words in a text box. I have tried to insert word count in the text box but didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

#### I need to set a limit on words in a text box

- Double click the Text Box (in design mode)
- Enable "Limit text box" and then enter the number of characters for your limit.
- The limit will be in effect after you have enforced protection (in the Restrict Formatting and Editing task pane) on the document.

---

> After you insert a text box on a form template, you can customize it by accessing and changing its properties and settings in the Text Box Properties dialog box. To open the dialog box, on the form template, double-click the text box whose properties you want to change.
>
> The following table describes some of the ways in which you can customize a text box and offers reasons why you might do so. Although the table doesn't provide detailed procedural information about the options in the Text Box Properties dialog box, it does give you an idea of the range of options that are available.

...

> To assign a character limit to a text box, select the Limit text box to check box, and then type the allowable number of characters.

Source [Ways to customize a text box](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/ways-to-customize-a-text-box-HA010094890.aspx)